# How to connect to sql server db on server by domain name

Tags: c#, sql

How can I connect to sql server database by domain name?

Comment: Can you specify in more detail what your question / problem is?

Comment: This question is on the verge of being a real question. Please elaborate!

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect only by only domain name (presuming you mean DNS domain name or windows domain name) as there could be multiple SQL Server instances running inside any given domain.  You must know the name of the server and database you are trying to connect to, and in cases where one server is running more than one instance, you must also have the instance name.

Answer (score 0):

Check out all the ConnectionString examples on

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0):

Fully qualifying the server name will specify the domain.

MySqlServer.MyDomain.COM